# Automatically resize third-party flutter widget with default sizes

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using flutter [numberpicker](https://pub.dev/packages/numberpicker) to build a mobile app. The default size of the widget is 50px by 100px. The size is too large for small screens. How should I make it automatically resize by specifying the right height and width?

Thanks. Any ideas and thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `SizedBox` and `FittedBox` to achieve any kind of scale manipulation of `Widget`s.

For your case, you can use it like this,

```
SizedBox(
  width: 75,
  child: FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.contain,
    child: NumberPicker(
      value: _currentValue,
      minValue: 0,
      maxValue: 100,
      onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _currentValue = value),
    ),
  ),
),
```

If you use it normally or don't give the `width` param in above code, tt looks like this.

[image]

But if you give a `width` of `75` like in the code above, it looks like this.

[image]

Comment: @expectedAn Does this solve your use case ?

Comment: Thanks @Nisanth, I will give it a try. If it works I will accept your answer.

Comment: @expectedAn Alright. Do tell me if anything breaks or doesn't work, would love to solve it.